# Illegal string offset 'single' on WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this a lot in my error log file:

```
[13-May-2020 18:09:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'single' in /website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 255
```

When i open the file it shows this:

```
// Add Cxense Tagging 
add_action('wp_head', 'cxense_meta_tag');
function cxense_meta_tag($urlcheck)
{
    switch ($urlcheck["single"]) {   //this is line 255
        case '0':

            echo("<p style='display: none;'>".$urlcheck["id"]."</p>");
            cxense_script($urlcheck["id"]);
            $post = get_post();
            if ($urlcheck["id"] != 71201) {

            ?>
```

From what I read, this problem can be fixed by using isset, but where should I add the isset?

Answer (score 1):

Surround your switch block with

```
if (isset($urlcheck['single'])) {
   switch ...
}
```

Alternative way could be:

```
if (!isset($urlcheck['single'])) {
   return;
}

switch ...
```

Comment: The second one is put the end of the if before the beginning of the switch?

Comment: yes, the return stops the execution of the function. if you are required to run through the switch you could also set a default value instead of return.